# how to change folder to subdomain in window hosting?

Tags: html, .htaccess

i have to make a blog via Google blog spot. but now i have to make a word press blog... now i have to deleted blog spot account... and also make a sub domain same name 'blog' but currently Google blog spot not working is showing.

i also made a word press blog in other name... now i want when anyone open..

> www.domain-name.com/folder-name

then this will automatic change URL  as

> folder-name.domain-name.com

Comment: http://blog.rnbresearch.com/ --- i want open same url with this http://www.rnbresearch.com/blog/ website... want to set url setting...